# Putting if and else in Foreach loop in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

When I wrote the `if and else` statement in a foreach loop, I have encountered an  error. I'm not sure what went wrong. I even added `@if` and `@var{  };` to the code. But there is still error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it stated was the '}'

Comment: The parser is confused when you don't close the tags when you inserted the else block in the middle of your html. What are you trying to do with that conditional block? Try to write out two complete and valid html snippets instead of mixing C# code with html.

Comment: @Jasen can you show me where is it? But I've already closed it.

Comment: Remove all your html from the for loop. Then slowly introduce it back. Your `<a>` and parent `<div>` are not closed.

Comment: @Jasen     but i've already closed it up at the bottom. Can you show me an example?

Comment: If that block does not meet the conditions the opening (or closing) tags will not be written. It will really help to help you if you could more clearly explain what your code is trying to do so someone can attempt to rewrite it.

Comment: The first `@item.HeaderPath` does not need `@` either.

Comment: @Jasen it's basically trying to display the image in the header when the QRCode image  is scanned by using the URL, if there's no image it will display the `scanIcon'

Comment: HeaderPath is a column name of the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mix partial html fragments with conditional C#/Razor code. The code might repeat but it's far easier to read and maintain later.

I may not have captured your intent correctly, but I can read this and understand how the condition affects the output.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var HeaderImage = item.HeaderPath;

    if (image != "")
    {
        var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(@"\\mainPage.com", "");
        <div class="picGallery">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.HeaderPath)" alt="Image" />

            <a href="@Url.Action("ViewPage", "Home")">
            </a>
            <div class="desc2">
                <p style="font-size: 13;">@item.Text</p>
                <p style="font-size: 13;">@item.text_2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="picGallery">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.HeaderPath)" alt="Image" />

            <a href="@Url.Action("ViewPage", "Home")">
                <div id="scanIcon">
                    <img src=img.png alt="imageView" />
                    <h1 style="font-size: 10px;">View Image</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="desc2">
                <p style="font-size: 13;">@item.Text</p>
                <p style="font-size: 13;">@item.text_2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

You can shorten this. But you need to be careful to escape the `@if` the nested blocks of code within html. It also becomes more difficult to understand what the output should be.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var HeaderImage = item.HeaderPath;

    <div class="picGallery">
        <img src="@Url.Content(item.HeaderPath)" alt="Image" />

        <a href="@Url.Action("ViewPage", "Home")">
            @if (image != "")
            {
                // image exists
                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(@"\\mainPage.com", "");

                <div>  </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="scanIcon">
                    <img src=img.png alt="imageView" />
                    <h1 style="font-size: 10px;">View Image</h1>
                </div>
            }
        </a>
        <div class="desc2">
            <p style="font-size: 13;">@item.Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```